# Why did the align by time query get timeout when running in version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After upgrading from version 1.2 to version 1.3, what may be the reason for the problem with `align by time`? This kind of query got timeout when older version did not generate this problem. Within the time range I set, only one device has data, so it should not be relevant to the amount of data is too large. Also, the devices corresponding to the time series paths are all different, so it should also not because of the replication of the device name. What other reason may explain why this problem happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `align by device` to your query statement, and check whether the data returned has duplicate timestamps for the same device of Apache IoTDB. If having the same timestamps, then your problem is caused by a merge bug. This duplicate timestamp will cause an infinite loop when using `time join`. You can delete the data with repeated timestamps and re-insert it, and later version will fix this bug.